# Magento 2.3.x multi node cluster

Tags: magento2.3.2

I need to create a magento cluster with multiple node, I created one using AWS quick start and was able to deploy it with two instances. by default it has only pub/media mounted and share between both instances, however, when I generate static content it does not work correctly since pub/static is not shared, I Installed a plugin using composer and I had to install it separately on both the instances. I am assuming I will have to share pub/static too. any ideas which other directories should be shared between both instances?

thanks